# Getting user full name upon facebook login Android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to add a facebook login to an android app.  While the login button and logging in works fine, I am also trying to obtain the first and last name of the user when they log in.  However, the String username always stays null.  Below is the complete code of this activity:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
private TextView info;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.fb_login_activity);
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);


    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            setData();
            if(username != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookLoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("username", username);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setData(){
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
        final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null){
                            try {
                                username = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name")+ " " + response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: there is no username field in the user table. at least not anymore.